# Telethon trouble: NameError: name 'events' is not defined

Tags: python, telethon

I am stuck in the middle with this code

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync

api_id = 99999
api_hash = 'secret_word'

client = TelegramClient('baracuda', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=('tester')))
async def normal_handler(event):
#    print(event.message)
    print(event.message.to_dict()['message'])

client.start()

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

I always have error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                    
File "notification.py", line 9, in <module>                           
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=('chat_name')))
NameError: name 'events' is not defined
```

Please, help me to solve this issue

Comment: You forgot the import `from telethon import events`

Comment: it works. thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small mistake, You have to add:

```
from telethon import events
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: for all code: `from telethon import TelegramClient, sync, events` or just `from telethon import *` if needed